# iOS cordova build throwing bad access exception immediately after launch, majority of the time

Tags: ios, cordova

Seen similar issues to this on the net, but no solutions. It seems to have cropped up with iOS 8. With NSZombie turned on, I see the error:

```
[UIViewAnimationState release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1701c9d80
```

Then the stack of memory addresses in the webthread:

```
CoreFoundation`___forwarding___:
    0x18708fdb4 <+0>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #-80]!
    0x18708fdb8 <+4>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #16]
    0x18708fdbc <+8>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #32]
    0x18708fdc0 <+12>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #48]
    0x18708fdc4 <+16>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #64]
    0x18708fdc8 <+20>:  add    x29, sp, #64
    0x18708fdcc <+24>:  sub    sp, sp, #32
    0x18708fdd0 <+28>:  mov    x22, x1
    0x18708fdd4 <+32>:  mov    x20, x0
    0x18708fdd8 <+36>:  ldr    x19, [x20]
    0x18708fddc <+40>:  and    x8, x19, #0x7000000000000000
    0x18708fde0 <+44>:  cmp    x19, #0
    0x18708fde4 <+48>:  ccmp   x8, #0, #0, lt
    0x18708fde8 <+52>:  b.eq   0x18708ffe8               ; <+564>
    0x18708fdec <+56>:  ldr    x21, [x20, #8]
    0x18708fdf0 <+60>:  mov    x0, x19
    0x18708fdf4 <+64>:  bl     0x1870f2f58               ; symbol stub for: +[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:]
    0x18708fdf8 <+68>:  mov    x23, x0
    0x18708fdfc <+72>:  bl     0x1870f2db4               ; symbol stub for: __destroy_helper_block_167
    0x18708fe00 <+76>:  mov    x24, x0
    0x18708fe04 <+80>:  adrp   x8, 74051
    0x18708fe08 <+84>:  nop    
    0x18708fe0c <+88>:  ldr    x25, [x8, #384]
    0x18708fe10 <+92>:  mov    x0, x23
    0x18708fe14 <+96>:  mov    x1, x25
    0x18708fe18 <+100>: bl     0x1870f2dd8               ; symbol stub for: __destroy_helper_block_171
    0x18708fe1c <+104>: cbz    w0, 0x18708fe58           ; <+164>
    0x18708fe20 <+108>: mov    x0, x19
    0x18708fe24 <+112>: mov    x1, x25
    0x18708fe28 <+116>: mov    x2, x21
    0x18708fe2c <+120>: bl     0x1870f2ec8               ; symbol stub for: -[NSOrderedSet initWithObject:]
    0x18708fe30 <+124>: cmp    x0, #0
    0x18708fe34 <+128>: ccmp   x0, x19, #4, ne
    0x18708fe38 <+132>: b.eq   0x18708fe58               ; <+164>
    0x18708fe3c <+136>: and    x8, x0, #0x7000000000000000
    0x18708fe40 <+140>: cmp    x0, #0
    0x18708fe44 <+144>: ccmp   x8, #0, #0, lt
    0x18708fe48 <+148>: b.eq   0x18708ffe4               ; <+560>
    0x18708fe4c <+152>: str    x0, [x20]
    0x18708fe50 <+156>: movz   x20, #0
    0x18708fe54 <+160>: b      0x187090024               ; <+624>
    0x18708fe58 <+164>: adrp   x1, 514
    0x18708fe5c <+168>: add    x1, x1, #2751
    0x18708fe60 <+172>: movz   x2, #0xa
    0x18708fe64 <+176>: mov    x0, x24
    0x18708fe68 <+180>: bl     0x1870f3dec               ; symbol stub for: __destroy_helper_block_467
    0x18708fe6c <+184>: cbz    w0, 0x187090044           ; <+656>
    0x18708fe70 <+188>: adrp   x8, 74051
    0x18708fe74 <+192>: nop    
    0x18708fe78 <+196>: ldr    x24, [x8, #328]
    0x18708fe7c <+200>: mov    x0, x23
    0x18708fe80 <+204>: mov    x1, x24
    0x18708fe84 <+208>: bl     0x1870f2dd8               ; symbol stub for: __destroy_helper_block_171
    0x18708fe88 <+212>: tbz    w0, #0, 0x187090094       ; <+736>
    0x18708fe8c <+216>: mov    x0, x19
    0x18708fe90 <+220>: mov    x1, x24
    0x18708fe94 <+224>: mov    x2, x21
    0x18708fe98 <+228>: bl     0x1870f2ec8               ; symbol stub for: -[NSOrderedSet initWithObject:]
    0x18708fe9c <+232>: mov    x24, x0
    0x18708fea0 <+236>: cbz    x24, 0x1870900e8          ; <+820>
    0x18708fea4 <+240>: adrp   x8, 74051
    0x18708fea8 <+244>: nop    
    0x18708feac <+248>: ldr    x1, [x8, #280]
    0x18708feb0 <+252>: mov    x0, x24
    0x18708feb4 <+256>: bl     0x1870f2ec8               ; symbol stub for: -[NSOrderedSet initWithObject:]
    0x18708feb8 <+260>: mov    x23, x0
    0x18708febc <+264>: ldr    x8, [x23]
    0x18708fec0 <+268>: ldrh   w8, [x8, #34]
    0x18708fec4 <+272>: ubfx   x8, x8, #6, #1
    0x18708fec8 <+276>: cmp    x8, x22
    0x18708fecc <+280>: b.eq   0x18708ff18               ; <+356>
    0x18708fed0 <+284>: mov    x0, x21
    0x18708fed4 <+288>: bl     0x1870f2fa0               ; symbol stub for: -[NSMutableOrderedSet setObject:atIndex:]
    0x18708fed8 <+292>: ldr    x8, [x23]
    0x18708fedc <+296>: ldrh   w8, [x8, #34]
    0x18708fee0 <+300>: adrp   x9, 535
    0x18708fee4 <+304>: add    x9, x9, #4044
    0x18708fee8 <+308>: tst    w8, #0x40
    0x18708feec <+312>: adrp   x8, 506
    0x18708fef0 <+316>: add    x8, x8, #1640
    0x18708fef4 <+320>: csel   x10, x8, x9, ne
    0x18708fef8 <+324>: cmp    x22, #0
    0x18708fefc <+328>: csel   x8, x8, x9, ne
    0x18708ff00 <+332>: str    x8, [sp, #16]
    0x18708ff04 <+336>: stp    x0, x10, [sp]
    0x18708ff08 <+340>: adrp   x1, 74021
    0x18708ff0c <+344>: add    x1, x1, #3760
    0x18708ff10 <+348>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x4
    0x18708ff14 <+352>: bl     0x187071f88               ; CFLog
    0x18708ff18 <+356>: adrp   x8, 74051
    0x18708ff1c <+360>: ldr    x0, [x8, #2360]
    0x18708ff20 <+364>: nop    
    0x18708ff24 <+368>: nop    
    0x18708ff28 <+372>: ldr    x1, [x8, #344]
    0x18708ff2c <+376>: mov    x2, x24
    0x18708ff30 <+380>: mov    x3, x20
    0x18708ff34 <+384>: bl     0x1870f2ec8               ; symbol stub for: -[NSOrderedSet initWithObject:]
    0x18708ff38 <+388>: mov    x21, x0
    0x18708ff3c <+392>: mov    x0, x19
    0x18708ff40 <+396>: bl     0x1870f2f58               ; symbol stub for: +[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:]
    0x18708ff44 <+400>: adrp   x8, 74051
    0x18708ff48 <+404>: nop    
    0x18708ff4c <+408>: ldr    x22, [x8, #392]
    0x18708ff50 <+412>: mov    x1, x22
    0x18708ff54 <+416>: bl     0x1870f2dd8               ; symbol stub for: __destroy_helper_block_171
    0x18708ff58 <+420>: cbz    w0, 0x18708ff70           ; <+444>
    0x18708ff5c <+424>: mov    x0, x19
    0x18708ff60 <+428>: mov    x1, x22
    0x18708ff64 <+432>: mov    x2, x21
    0x18708ff68 <+436>: bl     0x1870f2ec8               ; symbol stub for: -[NSOrderedSet initWithObject:]
    0x18708ff6c <+440>: b      0x18708ff8c               ; <+472>
    0x18708ff70 <+444>: mov    x0, x19
    0x18708ff74 <+448>: bl     0x1870f2f64               ; symbol stub for: +[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithSet:copyItems:]
    0x18708ff78 <+452>: stp    x19, x0, [sp]
    0x18708ff7c <+456>: adrp   x1, 74021
    0x18708ff80 <+460>: add    x1, x1, #3792
    0x18708ff84 <+464>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x4
    0x18708ff88 <+468>: bl     0x187071f88               ; CFLog
    0x18708ff8c <+472>: adrp   x8, 74051
    0x18708ff90 <+476>: ldrsw  x8, [x8, #3972]
    0x18708ff94 <+480>: ldrb   w8, [x21, x8]
    0x18708ff98 <+484>: cbz    w8, 0x18708ffd4           ; <+544>
    0x18708ff9c <+488>: ldr    x8, [x23]
    0x18708ffa0 <+492>: ldrb   w9, [x8, #34]
    0x18708ffa4 <+496>: tbz    w9, #7, 0x18708ffd4       ; <+544>
    0x18708ffa8 <+500>: adrp   x9, 74051
    0x18708ffac <+504>: ldrsw  x9, [x9, #3964]
    0x18708ffb0 <+508>: ldr    x9, [x21, x9]
    0x18708ffb4 <+512>: ldr    w10, [x8, #28]
    0x18708ffb8 <+516>: ldrb   w11, [x8, #32]
    0x18708ffbc <+520>: add    x10, x11, x10
    0x18708ffc0 <+524>: ldr    x0, [x20, x10]
    0x18708ffc4 <+528>: ldr    x1, [x9, x10]
    0x18708ffc8 <+532>: ldr    x8, [x8]
    0x18708ffcc <+536>: ldr    w2, [x8, #16]
    0x18708ffd0 <+540>: bl     0x1870f39fc               ; symbol stub for: __NSOrderedSetEnumerate
    0x18708ffd4 <+544>: adrp   x8, 74051
    0x18708ffd8 <+548>: ldrsw  x8, [x8, #3960]
    0x18708ffdc <+552>: ldr    x20, [x21, x8]
    0x18708ffe0 <+556>: b      0x187090024               ; <+624>
    0x18708ffe4 <+560>: mov    x19, x0
    0x18708ffe8 <+564>: mov    x0, x19
    0x18708ffec <+568>: bl     0x18709399c               ; getAtomTarget
    0x18708fff0 <+572>: mov    x21, x0
    0x18708fff4 <+576>: str    x21, [x20]
    0x18708fff8 <+580>: adrp   x0, 73983
    0x18708fffc <+584>: ldr    x0, [x0, #384]
    0x187090000 <+588>: orr    x3, xzr, #0x400
    0x187090004 <+592>: mov    x1, x20
    0x187090008 <+596>: mov    x2, x20
    0x18709000c <+600>: movz   w4, #0
    0x187090010 <+604>: bl     0x187092070               ; __invoking___
    0x187090014 <+608>: ldr    x8, [x20]
    0x187090018 <+612>: cmp    x8, x21
    0x18709001c <+616>: b.ne   0x187090024               ; <+624>
    0x187090020 <+620>: str    x19, [x20]
    0x187090024 <+624>: mov    x0, x20
    0x187090028 <+628>: sub    sp, x29, #64
    0x18709002c <+632>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #64]
    0x187090030 <+636>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #48]
    0x187090034 <+640>: ldp    x22, x21, [sp, #32]
    0x187090038 <+644>: ldp    x24, x23, [sp, #16]
    0x18709003c <+648>: ldp    x26, x25, [sp], #80
    0x187090040 <+652>: ret    
    0x187090044 <+656>: adrp   x8, 74066
    0x187090048 <+660>: add    x8, x8, #288
    0x18709004c <+664>: ldrb   w8, [x8]
    0x187090050 <+668>: cbz    w8, 0x18709006c           ; <+696>
    0x187090054 <+672>: movz   x2, #0
    0x187090058 <+676>: movz   w0, #0x15
    0x18709005c <+680>: mov    x1, x19
    0x187090060 <+684>: movz   x3, #0
    0x187090064 <+688>: movz   x4, #0
    0x187090068 <+692>: bl     0x187045204               ; __CFRecordAllocationEvent
    0x18709006c <+696>: add    x20, x24, #10
    0x187090070 <+700>: mov    x0, x21
    0x187090074 <+704>: bl     0x1870f2fa0               ; symbol stub for: -[NSMutableOrderedSet setObject:atIndex:]
    0x187090078 <+708>: mov    x8, x0
    0x18709007c <+712>: stp    x8, x19, [sp, #8]
    0x187090080 <+716>: str    x20, [sp]
    0x187090084 <+720>: adrp   x8, 74020
    0x187090088 <+724>: add    x8, x8, #3600
    0x18709008c <+728>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x3
    0x187090090 <+732>: b      0x187090174               ; <+960>
    0x187090094 <+736>: mov    x0, x23
    0x187090098 <+740>: bl     0x1870f2dc0               ; symbol stub for: ___CFPreferencesRemoveSuitePreferencesFromAppWithContainer_block_invoke169
    0x18709009c <+744>: mov    x22, x0
    0x1870900a0 <+748>: mov    x0, x19
    0x1870900a4 <+752>: bl     0x1870f2f64               ; symbol stub for: +[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithSet:copyItems:]
    0x1870900a8 <+756>: mov    x20, x0
    0x1870900ac <+760>: cbnz   x22, 0x1870900d0          ; <+796>
    0x1870900b0 <+764>: mov    x0, x19
    0x1870900b4 <+768>: bl     0x1870f2f64               ; symbol stub for: +[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithSet:copyItems:]
    0x1870900b8 <+772>: mov    x8, x0
    0x1870900bc <+776>: stp    x20, x8, [sp, #8]
    0x1870900c0 <+780>: str    x19, [sp]
    0x1870900c4 <+784>: adrp   x8, 74020
    0x1870900c8 <+788>: add    x8, x8, #3632
    0x1870900cc <+792>: b      0x1870900dc               ; <+808>
    0x1870900d0 <+796>: stp    x19, x20, [sp]
    0x1870900d4 <+800>: adrp   x8, 74020
    0x1870900d8 <+804>: add    x8, x8, #3664
    0x1870900dc <+808>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x4
    0x1870900e0 <+812>: mov    x1, x8
    0x1870900e4 <+816>: bl     0x187071f88               ; CFLog
    0x1870900e8 <+820>: mov    x0, x21
    0x1870900ec <+824>: bl     0x1870f2fa0               ; symbol stub for: -[NSMutableOrderedSet setObject:atIndex:]
    0x1870900f0 <+828>: mov    x20, x0
    0x1870900f4 <+832>: bl     0x1870f2fac               ; symbol stub for: -[NSMutableOrderedSet setObject:atIndexedSubscript:]
    0x1870900f8 <+836>: mov    x8, x0
    0x1870900fc <+840>: cmp    x8, x21
    0x187090100 <+844>: b.eq   0x187090120               ; <+876>
    0x187090104 <+848>: stp    x20, x8, [sp, #8]
    0x187090108 <+852>: str    x21, [sp]
    0x18709010c <+856>: adrp   x8, 74020
    0x187090110 <+860>: add    x8, x8, #3696
    0x187090114 <+864>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x4
    0x187090118 <+868>: mov    x1, x8
    0x18709011c <+872>: bl     0x187071f88               ; CFLog
    0x187090120 <+876>: mov    x0, x19
    0x187090124 <+880>: bl     0x1870f2f58               ; symbol stub for: +[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:]
    0x187090128 <+884>: adrp   x8, 74049
    0x18709012c <+888>: nop    
    0x187090130 <+892>: ldr    x20, [x8, #3456]
    0x187090134 <+896>: mov    x1, x20
    0x187090138 <+900>: bl     0x1870f2dd8               ; symbol stub for: __destroy_helper_block_171
    0x18709013c <+904>: mov    x8, x0
    0x187090140 <+908>: cbz    w8, 0x187090158           ; <+932>
    0x187090144 <+912>: mov    x0, x19
    0x187090148 <+916>: mov    x1, x20
    0x18709014c <+920>: mov    x2, x21
    0x187090150 <+924>: bl     0x1870f2ec8               ; symbol stub for: -[NSOrderedSet initWithObject:]
    0x187090154 <+928>: brk    #0x1
    0x187090158 <+932>: mov    x0, x19
    0x18709015c <+936>: bl     0x1870f2f64               ; symbol stub for: +[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithSet:copyItems:]
    0x187090160 <+940>: mov    x8, x0
    0x187090164 <+944>: stp    x19, x8, [sp]
    0x187090168 <+948>: adrp   x8, 74020
    0x18709016c <+952>: add    x8, x8, #3728
    0x187090170 <+956>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x4
    0x187090174 <+960>: mov    x1, x8
    0x187090178 <+964>: bl     0x187071f88               ; CFLog
->  0x18709017c <+968>: brk    #0x1
```

Sometimes the app will build fine, and I can run it without issue. But other times it just crashes after pressing Run in XCode. I'm using the latest XCode on OS X Yosemite. Building for an iPad mini retina running 8.3

**Edit**

Stack trace from lldb:

```
* thread #9: tid = 0x14e8ec, 0x000000018709017c CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 968, name = 'WebThread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18709017c)
  * frame #0: 0x000000018709017c CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 968
    frame #1: 0x0000000186f92ccc CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    frame #2: 0x0000000186f69458 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 524
    frame #3: 0x000000018b410b3c QuartzCore`CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*) + 32
    frame #4: 0x000000018b416b50 QuartzCore`-[CAAnimation dealloc] + 84
    frame #5: 0x0000000198551724 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 564
    frame #6: 0x0000000186f6d074 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
    frame #7: 0x0000000187eacffc Foundation`-[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 152
    frame #8: 0x0000000186acdd80 CFNetwork`AutoAutoreleasePool::~AutoAutoreleasePool() + 36
    frame #9: 0x0000000186aa9588 CFNetwork`___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 228
    frame #10: 0x00000001869cbac8 CFNetwork`RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 76
    frame #11: 0x0000000186f6ccdc CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    frame #12: 0x00000001869cb974 CFNetwork`RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 136
    frame #13: 0x00000001869cb828 CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::perform() + 312
    frame #14: 0x00000001869cb654 CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 68
    frame #15: 0x0000000187044240 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    frame #16: 0x00000001870434e4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
    frame #17: 0x0000000187041594 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 712
    frame #18: 0x0000000186f6d2d4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
    frame #19: 0x0000000195618894 WebCore`RunWebThread(void*) + 468
    frame #20: 0x0000000198d6bdc8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 164
    frame #21: 0x0000000198d6bd24 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 160
```

Comment: That's not the stack; that's the disassembly for the `___forwarding___` function of the `CoreFoundation` library.  We don't care about that; we could disassemble `___forwarding___` ourselves if we really needed to.

Comment: Ah okay. Just where the error popped up in xcode.

Comment: Right.  The app crashed in the `___forwarding___` function.  You've probably noticed that when the app crashes, the debugger shows the code that it crashes in.  But the debugger doesn't have the code for this function since it's not part of your app; it's part of `CoreFoundation`, so it disassembles the machine code.

Comment: To get the actual stack trace, type `bt` into the debugger console (at the `(lldb)` prompt).

Comment: Thanks, added the results from that.